# Why is an instance specification not required for class in separate file?

Tags: java

If I have a class such as:

```
public class Main {
    public class CommandLineParser {

        public CommandLineParser(String[] args) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        new CommandLineParser(args); // <<< line in question    
    }
}
```

then I, quite reasonably, get an error message:

> No enclosing instance of type `Main` is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type `Main` (e.g. `x.new A()` where `x` is an instance of `Main`).

But if I move class `CommandLineParser` to a separate file there are no such complaints.

Why is there no error in the second case?

(NOTE:  This question is NOT how to instantiate non static inner class within a static method.)

Comment: Sample IS complete.  Copied and pasted direct from the editor.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to create a static nested class instead of an inner class?

Comment: @Zabuza: Irrelevant, removed.

Comment: @Keiwan: Isn't that the opposite question?  I EXPECTED to have to code x.new because of that, but if the class is external I do NOT have to.  What have I missed?

Comment: It's no longer a nested class once it's in its own source file. It's a regular top level class.

Comment: @Kayaman:  OK, but it's still NOT static.  Why doesn't it require an instance there?

Comment: An instance of what? A non-static **nested** class requires an instance of the **enclosing** class. If you don't **have** an enclosing class (if you move the class to its own file it'll be a regular top level class), what instance would you even IMAGINE requiring? The duplicates explain perfectly how nested classes work.

Comment: @Kayaman:  Ah!  Your emboldening clarifies it.  Many thanks.

Comment: Well it's a good thing it didn't go to *waste* :)